# How to produce favicon <link> using JSF?

Tags: jsf-2

Is there a way using standard jsf-taglibs, which is rendered to `<link>` in the browser? My main goal is to produce a favicon link that should look like this:

`<link href="/portal/faces/javax.faces.resource/image/favicon.ico?ln=some.lib" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />`

Comment: I think the question is ok, but what are the reasons for not using html right away?

Comment: Actually all tries setting this in a more "static" manor failed; if I simply copy the marked code into my template it's reduced to `<link href="image/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />` which leads to a 404 for favicon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no standard JSF component/tag for this.

You can use `#{resource}` to convert a JSF resource identifier `libraryName:resourceName` to its domain-relative URL representation without the need to manually write down the context path, resource path, JSF mapping and query string.

```
<link href="#{resource['some.lib:image/favicon.ico']}" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

If you want to get a step further, then you can always wrap this in a custom tag file in the same line as `<h:outputStylesheet>` and friends like so:

```
<my:favicon library="some.lib" name="image/favicon.ico" />
```

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269)